# Part of screenshot appears black

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

I have a freeware app: [Graphing Calculator 3D](http://www.runiter.com/graphing-calculator/). It generates an image on the screen. I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print screen</kbd>. I open something like *Microsoft Paint*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and the screen cap of the window of the app appears in *Microsoft Paint*, but the specific area of the image on which I'm working always comes up black.

I get pretty much the same behavior with GreenShot.

I have never seen an app do this before. The pixels are on the screen. There should be some way of duplicating them. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the program it's trying to copy? There are some copy protections for various types of programs, so knowing what you're attempting to screenshot may help

Comment: @CanadianLuke  just edited my post.  First line has the app and the link to its page. I would like to know more about these "*copy protections*", as the last time I saw that phrase, it was reason to disqualify all consideration of the app in question. (Still is in my opinion)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't believe this is a duplicate, as it's not a video player, and the fact that the website has screenshots as well.

Comment: @CanadianLuke , Thank you for your interjection. I am also trying to see where the (putatively duplicate) other question addresses the same problem I'm having.  I don't see it at this time.

Comment: Remember, users (and even mods) can make mistakes, but we are still community run. Hopefully, more users can weigh in and help us decide.

Comment: I don't believe this question should be marked as duplicate. The reason part of the screenshots shows up black may be the same in both cases, but you can't expect that to be immediately obvious to anyone searching for a solution to this problem. Perhaps more importantly, the answers to the related question about video stills do not fully apply here.